# html5 canvas image compositing

Tags: image, html, html5-canvas, blending

Is there a way to overlay an image (jpeg) while keying out a certain color, like black? So that the all the pure black pixels in the image are transparent? Much like the "screen" blending mode in Photoshop?

I've tried looking into the `globalCompositeOperation` property of the canvas context, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to look into direct pixel manipulation. Slow but if speed is not as important as getting good results, do it.

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    inpos = y * width * 4; // *4 for 4 ints per pixel
    outpos = inpos + w2 * 4
    for (x = 0; x < w2; x++) {

        g = imageData.data[inpos++] / 3; 
        a = imageData.data[inpos++];     

        if( g > someValue )
              a = someNewAlpha;

        imageData.data[outpos++] = a;
    }
}
```

for more help see http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/

there's a number of ways in OpenGL but i'm not sure they would apply for your application, not knowing what it is supposed to do.